# TextWriter data missing but not throw exception

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have some codes process data like:

1. select data from database
2. write data to TXT file
3. update data flag in database

In little accident case, the data only write partly to the file, but data flag had been updated. My console application will send an email if it catches an exception. But I don't receive the email, so I suppose there is no exception been caught.

I have read some posts and documents about `StreamWriter`, and know the good practice when I try to fix this old application which I managed. But I'm curious if there are some possible reasons will affect I/O write or the error exception missing.

```cs
try
{
    using (Sqlconnection conn = new Sqlconnection) 
    {
        // codes select data from database
        ...

        // codes write file
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);
        sw.Write(aLongString);
        sw.Close();

        // codes update data in database
        ...
    }
}
catch {
    // codes send email here
}
```

Comment: Put `sw` in a `using`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks your advice. I have known that the good practice for using `StreamWriter` now, but still confused why it didn't throw exception.